# iOS 7: Multipeer Connectivity Framework

Tags: multipeer-connectivity

Has anybody an idea whether the MCF framework, without using the MCBrowserViewController (will be handled via MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate and MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate methods), will have a maximum number of peers allowed or not? (at least there is no public property to set it)

(for the MCBrowserViewController the default / maximum value is 8, details can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCBrowserViewController_class/MCBrowserViewController_class.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a second look into the `MCSession` header and did see that the limits being defined as constants (min = 2 and max = 8).

```
// Minimum number of peers in a session
MC_EXTERN NSUInteger const kMCSessionMinimumNumberOfPeers NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);

// Maximum number of peers in a 
MC_EXTERN NSUInteger const kMCSessionMaximumNumberOfPeers NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Comment: And to see for yourself what those values are, simply log these out in a class that imports MultipeerConnectivity: `NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)kMCSessionMaximumNumberOfPeers);` As of now, the max logs 8.